# how to raise a C# event or function in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a function in my login page an it access is protect like other C# function by default.

```
protected void MyFunction()
{
    //do somthing
}
```

I want to raise it in JavaScript something like this

```
<script>
    $.rise(MyFunction)
</script>
```

Someone said should use

```
__doPostBack(control, arg);
```

Or

```
<a .... onclick="TriggerPostBack('control', 'arg')" .. />
```

Or....
but all of this is for an ASP.NET object and if you use ASP.NET object it automatically generate callback and `__doPostBack` and everything you need.

Unfortunately I dont have an ASP.NET object and I use a simple HTML tag and  want to raise a c# function by JavaScript manually.
is it possible? and the access of function what should be? and about the security? is it logical or illogical?

At the end I want to postback happen because I am familiar with jQuery AJAX and in this case I dont need it. I want postback happen.

Comment: What kind of method do you want to raise? Maybe you should consider architectural changes (use AJAX or similar ways).

Comment: You need to specify what you are using. Is it some js app + ASP .NET server? Where is your js function, and where is your C# function?

Comment: @bash.d
actually I send the value of tow textbox contain of username and password to a web service using by $.ajax and get the response in it, then if the response in correct I should set a session and cookie in server but how? how to raise a function by javascript, notice that session and cookie should be set in server side function for security reason.

Comment: @MichałKędrzyński I use asp.net web application and js code is inside in login.aspx and the function is in code behind login.aspx.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method to a static webmethod and try an jquery ajax post.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "YourPage.aspx/MyFunction",
    data: '',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess,
    failure: function(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});

[WebMethod]
public static void MyFunction() 
{

}
```